# Excel: missing something in writing an enumeration function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Up front let me say I can do this in VBA but I am trying to do it without using VBA with the assistance of the new LAMBA function.

I have a list, let us say  A,B,C,D,C,E,B,B

what I am trying to write is an enumeration function which gives me the individual positions of set of identical items.  So in the above example it would return a list  1,1,1,1,2,1,2,3   (the last item is a three because it is the 3rd "b" element etc).  It is easy enough to do in cells with the answer in the next row:

a1:a8 contain  A,B,C,D,C,E,B,B

b1 contains =COUNTIF(A1:$A$1,A1) and that gets dragged across all the columns

But I need the output in a dynamic array and something like b1

=COUNTIF(A1:$A$1,A1:H1) obviously won't work.

I've also tried writing a recursive LAMBDA statement which runs through a diminishing range but that gives me VALUE errors and is pretty complex in any case.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65800004/9758194)? Re-written to maybe `=COUNTIFS(OFFSET(A1,0,0,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A:A))),A1:A8)`

Comment: @JvdV I knew I had done this before.

Comment: Yeah, was basically the first hit I got. Went looking for a non-volatile way. Though a bit verbose. I found one [here](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/1228064-running-count-of-occurrence-in-list-using-array-formula-with-spill-range/). I think I'd prefer the once-of volatile =)

Comment: I like that one.  I would tailor it to fit here.  If the data is large it will be quicker

Answer (score 4):

Use Offset inside the COuNTIFS:

```
=COUNTIF(OFFSET(A1,0,0,1,SEQUENCE(,COUNTA(1:1))),INDEX(1:1,,SEQUENCE(,COUNTA(1:1))))
```

[image]

---

For a non Volatile version use:

```
=MMULT(SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(A1:H1),1,0),(A1:H1=TRANSPOSE(A1:H1))*(SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(A1:H1))>=SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A1:H1))))
```

[image]

With LET:

```
=LET(x,A1:H1,y,COLUMNS(x),MMULT(SEQUENCE(,y,1,0),(x=TRANSPOSE(x))*(SEQUENCE(,y)>=SEQUENCE(y))))
```

Comment: I know not my question, but any chance of getting this sequence function for 2016 versions?

Comment: `COLUMN(A1:H1)` for static size: `COLUMN(A1:INDEX(1:1,MATCH("zzz",1:1)))` for dynamic size.

Comment: But personally I would just use: `=IF(A1<>"",COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1),"")` and copy over enough columns that it will always be enough.

Comment: OMG!! Great !! Thanks !!

Comment: I like the MMULT approach.  I confess that had not even occurred to me. Very nice,  Thanks